# indexableText not updating with Google Drive SDK

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Using the JavaScript v2 API for Google Drive, I got into a situation where newly created files seem to be nicely indexed for search, but no further file updates to the same ID actually change the meta-data. (so after a file is saved, I can still find it using the old content even when deleted, but no new content seems to return search results). Can anyone help with a pointer in the right direction? This happens when setting indexableText in metadata as well as useContentAsIndexableText in params. Here's a code snippet that we use:

```
boundary = '-------314159265358979323846',
delimiter = '\r\n--' + boundary + '\r\n',
closeDelim = '\r\n--' + boundary + '--',
data = JSON.stringify(mapInfo.idea),
metadata = {
    'title': mapInfo.idea.title + '.mup',
    'mimeType': contentType,
    'indexableText': {'text': contentSummary }
},
multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    data +
    closeDelim,
request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files' + (googleId ? '/' + googleId : ''),
    'method': (googleId ? 'PUT' : 'POST'),
    'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'fileId': googleId },
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=\'' + boundary + '\''
    },
    'body': multipartRequestBody
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the two are mutually exclusive. useContentAsIndexableText means that the content is indexable. indexableText is something you pass if your content is binary.